# Work with next row in rdlc table?

Tags: rdlc

I have a tablix in my `rdlc` report and i need to add a border bottom style if the next row have a different value from the actual row... is this possible?

Maybe an operator in the expression category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following on the border bottom style (expression):

```
=IIf(Previous(Fields!YourField.Value) = "Something") then "Solid" else "None"
```

Add this to color and width as well if you need to change those values too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have not tested this so it may need some tweaking

Comment: This will not work because i need to compare it to the next row... and i dont know if the next (or previous) row will be that "Something" value.

Comment: Try =IIf(Previous(Fields!YourField.Value) <> Fields!YourField.Value) then "Solid" else "None"

Comment: This will compare the current row value with the previous row value.

Comment: How can i do that but with the next row?

Comment: I finally ended by doing the top border and no the bottom border so this worked for me, thanks